# Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#home Hatrl's tuorial

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on Michael Hartl Rails tutorial (currently chapter 7). When I try to run server this message appear:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#home

Showing C:/rails_project/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line      #5 raised:

Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
(in C:/rails_project/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:     <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    

Rails.root: C:/rails_project/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:104
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___917874405_26658636'
```

Code from application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have no idea where is the problem. Error message seem to inadequate to code existing in aplication.html.erb. Anyone got clue?

Comment: If you cannot figure out the solution, post the app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss contents around line 104.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your style sheet:

> app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

Your app is using Sass (http://sass-lang.com) and there is a problem in the file listed above.  Fix the .scss error and the error message will go away.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to give you an errant line number within that .scss file.

Comment: It turned out that problem was very trivial: In custom.css.scss file I forgot last "}". Thanks you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message while doing this tutorial.

I realised that I had omitted a `;` at the end of the first line of code in `custom.css.scss`

instead of:

```
@import "bootstrap"
```

it needs to be:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using saas and in that you are using css "{}". In saas we don't use. Your saas will be parsed and compiled into css. For parsing saas follows different syntax. Here I will demonstrate an example of saas

```
.head
  width: 100%
  .in.out
    width: 50%
```

Note the above syntax. Here it means on element with class **"head" apply width 100%** and if the element with class **"in" and "out" is found in ".head"**, it should have **width 50%**. Also note spaces used for indentation should be same and after **"property:"** give a single space

Wrong way

```
width:100%
```

Right way

```
width: 100%
```